# How can I apply a vectorized function to the previous element of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I want to apply a function like this:

```
s[i] = a*x[i] + (1 - a)*s[i-1]
```

where `s` and `x` are both arrays of the same length.

I don't want to use a for loop as these arrays are very large (>50 mil). I have tried doing something like this

```
def f(a,x):
    s = [0]*len(x)
    s[i] = a*x[i] + (1 - a)*s[i-1]
    return s
```

but of course `i` isn't defined so this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this using `map` or `numpy.apply_along_axis` or some other vectorized method?

I haven't come across a method that applies functions to current and previous elements of an array without using for loops, and that is really what I want to understand how to do here.

**EDIT**

To be unambiguous, here is the for loop implementation which works but that I want to avoid

```
s = [0]*len(x)
a=0.45
for i in range(len(x)):
    s[i] = a*x[i] + (1-a)*s[i-1]

s[0] = x[0] # reset value of s[0]
```

Comment: 50k is not really large.. What would the new `s[0]` be btw? Does your formula hold for `i>0` only?

Comment: yes its only for i>0

Comment: Is `s[i-1]` supposed to be the value from the original `s`, or already the updated previous entry?

Comment: Can you change the calculation to work with `cumsum`, or other `ufunc` `accumulate` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in an [answer to basically the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48864958/4042267), you can't:

> There is no other way (in general) except for an explicit `for` loop.
>   This is because there is no way to parallelize this task across the
>   rows (since every row depends on some other row).
>
> What makes this even harder is that you can easily generate [chaotic
>   behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_behavior), for example with the seemingly innocent looking
>   [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map): `x_{n+1} = r * x_n * (1 - x_{n-1})`.
>
> You can only find a way around this if you manage to find a closed
>   form, essentially eliminating the recurrence relation. But this has to
>   be done for each recurrence relation and I am pretty sure you are not
>   even guaranteed that a closed form exists...

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the loop, although rather than vectorizing is more like "computing everything for each value".

```
import numpy as np

# Loop
def fun(x, a):
    s = [0] * len(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        s[i] = a * x[i] + (1 - a) * s[i - 1]
    s[0] = x[0]
    return s

# Vectorized
def fun_vec(x, a):
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float32)
    n = np.arange(len(x))
    p = a * (1 - a) ** n
    # Trick from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49532575/1782792
    pz = np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(p) - 1, dtype=p.dtype), p))
    pp = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        pz[len(p) - 1:], (len(p), len(p)),
        (p.strides[0], -p.strides[0]), writeable=False)
    t = x[np.newaxis] * pp
    s = np.sum(t, axis=1)
    s[0] = x[0]
    return s


x = list(range(1, 11))
a = 0.45
print(np.allclose(fun(x, a), fun_vec(x, a)))
# True
```

This kind of strategy is takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) memory though, and it is more computation. Depending on the case it can be faster due to parallelism (I did something similar to eliminate a `tf.while_loop` in TensorFlow to great success), but in this case it is actually slower:

```
x = list(range(1, 101))
a = 0.45
%timeit fun(x, a)
# 31 µs ± 85.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit fun_vec(x, a)
# 147 µs ± 2.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So, there can be a non-loop version, but it is more of a curiosity than anything else.