# Make matrix from consecutive array slices or rolls

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like:

```
[10 20 30 40]
```

And I want to build a matrix `M1` like this:

```
10  0  0  0
20 10  0  0
30 20 10  0
40 30 20 10
```

My approach is to first build the following matrix `M2` out of consecutive "rolls" of the array:

```
10 20 30 40
20 10 40 30
30 20 10 40
40 30 20 10
```

And then take the lower triangular matrix with [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html). I would be interested then in efficient methods to build `M2` or `M1` directly without through `M2`.

A simple way to build M2 could be:

```
import numpy as np

def M2_simple(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    return np.stack([a[np.arange(-i, len(a) - i)] for i in range(len(a))]).T

print(M2_simple(np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])))
# [[10 40 30 20]
#  [20 10 40 30]
#  [30 20 10 40]
#  [40 30 20 10]]
```

After some trying I came to the following, better solution, based on [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
def M2_indexing(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    r = np.arange(len(a))[np.newaxis]
    return a[np.newaxis][np.zeros_like(r), r - r.T].T
```

This is obviously much faster than the previous, but measuring the performance still seems not as fast as it could be (for example, it takes order of magnitude longer than tiling, not being a *so* different operation), and it requires me to build big indexing matrices.

Is there a better way to build these matrices?

Comment: likely terrible native python attempt `[y[::-1]+(len(lst)-i-1)*[0] for i,y in enumerate(itertools.accumulate(([x] for x in lst)))]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Interesting, I didn't think of a pure Python implementation. I'd probably go with just `[lst[i::-1] + [0] * (len(lst) - i - 1) for i in range(len(lst))]`.

Comment: Oh yah that's much cleaner, actually might not be too bad if you set `len_ = len(lst)` and `lst2 = [0]` *outside* the comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one using `as_strided` similar to [`@jdehesa's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532576/3293881) , but  with negative strides that saves us the flipping at the end, like so -

```
def strided_app2(a):
    n = len(a)
    ae = np.concatenate((np.zeros(n-1,dtype=a.dtype),a))
    s = a.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ae[n-1:],(n,n),(s,-s),writeable=False)
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: a
Out[66]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])

In [67]: strided_app2(a)
Out[67]: 
array([[10,  0,  0,  0],
       [20, 10,  0,  0],
       [30, 20, 10,  0],
       [40, 30, 20, 10]])
```

**Digging further**

Going deeper into the timings for each step, it's revealed that the bottleneck is the concatenation part. So, we can employ array-initialization, giving us an alternative one and seems to be much better for large arrays, like so -

```
def strided_app3(a):
    n = len(a)
    ae = np.zeros(2*n-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    ae[-n:] = a
    s = a.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ae[n-1:],(n,n),(s,-s),writeable=False)
```

Timings -

```
In [55]: a = np.random.rand(100000)

In [56]: %timeit M1_strided(a) #@jdehesa's soln
    ...: %timeit strided_app2(a)
    ...: %timeit strided_app3(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.5 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.4 µs per loop

In [61]: a = np.random.rand(1000000)

In [62]: %timeit M1_strided(a) #@jdehesa's soln
    ...: %timeit strided_app2(a)
    ...: %timeit strided_app3(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.02 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop

In [63]: a = np.random.rand(10000000)

In [64]: %timeit M1_strided(a) #@jdehesa's soln
    ...: %timeit strided_app2(a)
    ...: %timeit strided_app3(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.2 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 13.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Neat! I assume you can build `M1` in a similar way (see edit in my answer).

Comment: @jdehesa This builds `M1`. Or do you mean `M2`? I thought M1 was the final desired output, wasn't it?

Comment: Ah sorry you're right, I though you were trying to make `M2` because you were comparing to `M2_strided` (the comparison should be similar anyway I guess).

Comment: @jdehesa Ah my bad! Updated with the correct version from your post. Timings seem much closer now.

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT:*

Actually, you can build `M1` directly using the same method:

```
import numpy as np

def M1_strided(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = len(a)
    s, = a.strides
    a0 = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(a) - 1, a.dtype), a])
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        a0, (n, n), (s, s), writeable=False)[:, ::-1]

print(M1_strided(np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])))
# [[10  0  0  0]
#  [20 10  0  0]
#  [30 20 10  0]
#  [40 30 20 10]]
```

In this case the speed benefit is even better, since you are saving the call to [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html):

```
N = 100
a = np.square(np.arange(N))
%timeit np.tril(M2_simple(a))
# 792 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.tril(M2_indexing(a))
# 259 µs ± 9.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.tril(M2_strided(a))
# 134 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit M1_strided(a)
# 45.2 µs ± 583 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

You can build the `M2` matrix more efficiently with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def M2_strided(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = len(a)
    s, = a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        np.tile(a[::-1], 2), (n, n), (s, s), writeable=False)[::-1]
```

As an extra benefit, you will only use twice as much memory as the original array (as opposed to the squared size). You just need to be careful not to write to the array created like this (which should not be a problem if you are going to call [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) later on in) - I added `writeable=False` to disallow writing operations.

A quick speed comparison with IPython:

```
N = 100
a = np.square(np.arange(N))
%timeit M2_simple(a)
# 693 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit M2_indexing(a)
# 163 µs ± 1.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit M2_strided(a)
# 38.3 µs ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: It would be fair to move the `import ...` outside of the tested code-snippet, so as to leave the results indeed comparable to other methods.

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks, I've just removed inner imports.

Comment: **:o)** glad to see comparing apples to apples ( i.e.  including the necessary "outer"-`np.tril( ... )` for those non-strided fun-s ). **[ +1]** for this repair

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a builtin for that:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg as sl
>>> sl.toeplitz([10,20,30,40], [0,0,0,0])
array([[10,  0,  0,  0],
       [20, 10,  0,  0],
       [30, 20, 10,  0],
       [40, 30, 20, 10]])
```

Comment: Awesome, I wouldn't have found this in a lifetime. I assume the function solves a more general problem, since it seems to be slower (although not bad) than the strides-based solution, but definitely the fastest way to code it!

Comment: @jdehesa To be fair, it returns a contiguous array. So the user can write to it etc. without any unexpected behavior.