# Vectorizing a recurrence relation for-loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a recurrent relation that looks like the following:

```
f_0 = s_0
f_1 = alpha * s_1 + (1 - alpha) * f_0
f_2 = alpha * s_2 + (1 - alpha) * f_1
...
f_n = alpha * s_n + (1 - alpha) * f_n-1
```

this is easy enough to code up as a for-loop (example code)

```
import numpy as np
## values for example only ##
s = np.linspace(0, 10, 3000)
alpha = 1 / 5
f = s.copy()
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    f[i] = alpha * s[i] + (1 - alpha) * f[i-1]
```

my struggle is finding a way to vectorize this relation. I've tried being clever with slice indexing, but something like

```
f[1:] = alpha * s[1:] + (1 - alpha) * f[:-1]
```

is clearly not right, as it doesn't update `f`.

Is there an obvious way to vectorize this recurrence relation? I'd rather avoid this for-loop if I can, as my code will have to do this thousands of times as part of an optimization routine.

Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks for the feedback. I tried a naive numba implementation `@jit` and it actually made the loop 50x faster?! Being new to numba, is there any way to further tune these results?

Comment: Not sure this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864790/is-there-a-way-to-implement-recurrence-in-numpy-without-for-loops

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to vectorize this. However, you should be able to improve performance by using `numba`.

Comment: Can't you write down the solution directly: `f_n = alpha**n * (1-alpha)**n * prod(s[:n]) `?

Comment: Yeah, I'd second `numba`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970182/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336794/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391467/

Answer (score 0):

You could change this into a matrix equation. If you write f and s as numpy arrays (1d) and write a 2d numpy matrix M, such that:

```
F = numpy.dot(M,S)
```

then you only have to create the matrix once (it only depends on alpha), and can keep using it on different S.
On first inspection the matrix looks something like:

```
|1,0,0,0|
|(1-alpha),alpha,0,0|
|(1-alpha)^2,(1-alpha),alpha,0|
|(1-alpha)^3,(1-alpha)^2,(1-alpha),alpha|
```

Comment: that's not a bad idea to look into, but wouldn't the matrix need to be `n * n`? Where `n` is the length of the input?

Comment: Yes, it'll be square n*n, lower diagonal I think